# ExtJs Combobox with svg picture (highart) as value

Tags: javascript, extjs, svg, highcharts

I am using ExtJs 4.2.1 and want to do combobox with lines like this: `http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-dashstyle-all/`

I've already put svg pictures to the drop down, but i don't actually understand how to set value.

[image]

value always empty

[image]

```
model:

Ext.define('MyProj.model.GraphLineType', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'showName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'chartName', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

store:

Ext.define('MyProj.store.GraphLineType', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyProj.model.GraphLineType',
    autoLoad: false,
    data:[
        {showName: 'Solid', chartName: 'Solid'},
        {showName: 'ShortDash', chartName: 'ShortDash'},
        {showName: 'ShortDot', chartName: 'ShortDot'},
        {showName: 'ShortDot', chartName: 'ShortDashDot'},
        {showName: 'ShortDashDotDot', chartName: 'ShortDashDotDot'},
        {showName: 'Dot', chartName: 'Dot'},
        {showName: 'Dash', chartName: 'Dash'},
        {showName: 'LongDash', chartName: 'LongDash'},
        {showName: 'DashDot', chartName: 'DashDot'},
        {showName: 'LongDashDot', chartName: 'LongDashDot'},
        {showName: 'LongDashDotDot', chartName: 'LongDashDotDot'}
    ]
});


somewhere in view:
...
...
...
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Line type',
            store: 'GraphLineType',
            labelWidth: 140,
            width: 320,
            labelAlign: 'left',
            allowBlank: false,
            queryMode: 'local',
            step: 1,
            id: 'highchart_lines_combobox',
            hidden: false,
            valueField: 'chartName',
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for="."><div class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" id="combobox_item_{chartName}"></div></tpl>')
        },
...
...
...



somewhere in controller:

...
...
...
'#highchart_lines_combobox': {
            expand: function (field, eOpts) {
                var combobox = Ext.getCmp("highchart_lines_combobox");
                var store = combobox.getStore();
                if (!combobox.BEEN_EXPANDED) {
                        for (var i= 0, len=store.data.items.length; i<len; i++) {
                        var lineStyle = store.data.items[i].raw.chartName;
                        var elem = Ext.query("#combobox_item_"+lineStyle);
                        var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(elem[0], 380, 15);
                        renderer.path(['M', 2, 7, 'l', 380, 0]).attr({'stroke-width': 2, stroke: 'black', dashstyle: lineStyle}).add();
                    }
                }
                combobox.BEEN_EXPANDED = true;
            },
            change: function( cls, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) {
                HERE I NEET TO SET VALUE
                PLEASE HELP!!!
            }
        }
...
...
...
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do combobox with highcharts svg as values. 
Please help!

Comment: Why you cannot use images in dropdown, set correct value in select and then call action on chart which will update serie (series.update()) to apply new style.

Answer (score 0):

`valueField` is `chartName` so you can call

```
combo.setValue('LongDash');
```

for example.

Note: You do not need to set the new value in change event as the combo already has it and the handler function receives it as `newValue` argument.

Comment: of course not. I can't set picture as value. That was my question.

Comment: Hmm, combo is an id/text component where id (value) is used internally, not shown to user, and text (picture in your case) is that what the user sees in the dropdown. So chartName is a sort of index into pictures array, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am using chartName here: `var elem = Ext.query("#combobox_item_"+lineStyle);` lineStyle is chartName. That's how i get the div id to render there an picture